# e.OriginalSource is null

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a code where i get some text of textblock. I do this in a Hold Event using this code `txt = (e.OriginalSource as TextBlock).Text;` but sometimes it returns me this error **"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Barcode_QRCode.WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code"** and sometimes works just fine. Does anyone could help me here?

my code:

```
private void ListViewItem_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txt = (e.OriginalSource as TextBlock).Text;      

    MenuFlyout menu = new MenuFlyout();
    MenuFlyoutItem item1 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
    MenuFlyoutItem item2 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
    MenuFlyoutItem item3 = new MenuFlyoutItem();

    item1.Text = "Copiar";
    item2.Text = "Deletar";
    item3.Text = "Compartilhar";

    item1.Click += MenuFlyout_Copiar;
    item2.Click += MenuFlyout_Deletar;
    item3.Click += MenuFlyout_Compartilhar;

    menu.Items.Add(item1);
    menu.Items.Add(item2);
    menu.Items.Add(item3);

    menu.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
}
```

Comment: Its difficult to help you with the info provided. All I can say is that the `as` operator will return null if it can't convert the left side to the right side. You may want to verify that `e.OriginalSource` is not null and that the conversion is not null before trying to get the `.Text` property from it.

Comment: @JoséAugustoAcorsi it does not have to mean that `OriginalSource` is null? Have you confirmed that's the case? It could also mean that it's not `TextBlock` in which case `e.OriginalSource as TextBlock` will give you null

Answer (score 1):

Check if e.OriginalSource is null before attempting to cast and assign the value:

```
  Private void ListViewItem_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    txt = (e.OriginalSource != null ? (e.OriginalSource as TextBlock).Text : "");      

    MenuFlyout menu = new MenuFlyout();
    MenuFlyoutItem item1 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
    MenuFlyoutItem item2 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
    MenuFlyoutItem item3 = new MenuFlyoutItem();

    item1.Text = "Copiar";
    item2.Text = "Deletar";
    item3.Text = "Compartilhar";

    item1.Click += MenuFlyout_Copiar;
    item2.Click += MenuFlyout_Deletar;
    item3.Click += MenuFlyout_Compartilhar;

    menu.Items.Add(item1);
    menu.Items.Add(item2);
    menu.Items.Add(item3);

    menu.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sometimes the OriginalSource you receive is not a TextBlock, which will cause you cast to return null. You should check the type of your OriginalSource before trying to use it like so :

```
var textBlock = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
if(textBlock != null)
{
    ....
}
```